# Vue: How to use 'mapState' in mounted in a Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Ultimately, I want to call a value(`userSso`) of db and apply it to change `v-if` action 'earlier' before people can click.

So I wanted to use mounted hook but it didn't work. If I use functions at computed, then it was too slow that I could click "Account" even `userSso` is 1. What will be the better way?

**components/Lnb.vue**

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li :class="{ active: navbarState == 7 ? true : false }">
      <a href="/dashboard/settings">
        <img src="../assets/images/ico_settings.svg" alt="icon" /> Settings
      </a>
    </li>
    <li v-if="userSso == 0" :class="{ active: navbarState == 8 ? true : false }">
      <a href="/dashboard/user">
        <img src="../assets/images/ico_user.svg" alt="icon" />
        Account
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'Navbar',

  // props: ['userSso'],
  data() {
    return {
      visible: false,
      opened: false,
      navState: 0,
      itemcount: 0,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('store', {
      navbarState: (state) => state.navbarState,
      backColor: (state) => state.backColor,
      fontColor: (state) => state.fontColor,
      primaryColor: (state) => state.primaryColor,
      //pageSso: (state) => state.pageSso,
      //userSso: (state) => state.userSso,
    }),
  },
  mounted(){
    mapState('store', {
      userSso: (state) => {
        state.userSso
    }
    })
    console.log("mounted mapState userSso => ", userSso)

    
  },
  methods: {
  },
}
</script>
```

**/store/store.js**

```
export const state = () => ({
  userSso: 0,
})

...
```

Comment: Can't you just disable the button as long as you have no result?

Comment: There will be a result there and it will affect on the button so I can't just diable the button